# How to transition from the old flexbox to the new one?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been learning an outdated syntax of flexbox (2011 I think) which uses the old "box" properties (`-webkit-box, etc`). What is the best way to transition to the new `flex` model? Is there a chart or something with the conversions, or will I have to learn it like I am brand new?

Comment: This is a reasonable question for SO

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a nice chart, sorry, but I agree that it would be really helpful! You'll probably find that you *will* need to learn the new model from scratch, but your existing knowledge of the old model will help you a lot.

As far as I know, modern flexbox is a superset of the old "box" model, so transitioning is very possible, if not easy.

If you work backwards, with an auto-prefixing tool like "[Pleeease Play](http://pleeease.io/play/)", you can work out how the old syntax can be brought up to date.

For example, if you plug in this "new" syntax:

```
/* new syntax */
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.element {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

... the tool will generate the old `box` properties for you. (I've removed the "new syntax" properties for clarity)

```
/* old syntax */
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
}
.element {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
}
```

The new syntax is much more powerful: the `flex` property for example replaces the old `-webkit-box` property, but is also shorthand for `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`. There are other new properties too, such as `flex-wrap`, and many more. In this example, I've included the `-webkit` and `-ms` browser prefixes, but you may be able to leave those out depending on what browsers you need to support.